# Is there a blacksmith or forge in Strahd's realm?

Tags: dnd-5e, ravenloft

I have a dwarven PC that is interested in purchasing or creating some specialized items for himself while in Barovia. I don't recall anything of that nature spelled out explicitly in the book.

My question is twofold:

Is there a blacksmith/forge anywhere within Strahd's domain, and if not, do you foresee any major plot points that will crumble if I include a mundane one in one of the towns?

Answer (score 5):

The only description of anyone doing professional metalcrafting I could find is the general blurb about Vistani on p26 of CoS, which describes them as being silver and coppersmiths among other trades.

No major plot points crumble by the character obtaining items since presumably they could have brought items with them at level 3. Access to crafting for reasonable payment does detract from the tone set by the merchant in the village of Barovia and the need for players to scrabble for advantages. Not every Strahd game has to be an exercise in supply management survival horror though.

Comment: I was more worried about the believability of the story than any advantages they may gain. For example if there's some subplot about the farmers being unable to sow their fields because all the tools were long ago broken and nobody around can repair them... doesn't hold much water if Vallaki has a working blacksmith. I read the book and can't recall anything like that but figured it didn't hurt to tap into the knowledge base that is the Internet. Very much appreciate the response.

Answer (score -3):

Ok this is a straightforward answer that will probably annoy most people but, as the DM you can modify the published settings as much as you want, and you have to remember that keeping your players happy should be your primary concern. Because of this you can change a setting however you want so that it suits your players needs and wants in order to give them the best campaign possible.

If you're concerned about breaking the storyline of your campaign you can always attempt to modify it and create areas in the story that differ to the original version allowing your players to do what they like.

Comment: Hi Fiskell, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! I see from your Informed badge you've read our [tour], thanks for doing that. Generally answering a question about lore by saying "you're the DM, so you can do whatever you like" isn't useful since that was already taken as a given -- the question is seeking solid information on the defined lore. Pointing out they can change things to mitigate plot breakages is along the same lines, and doesn't answer whether there *will be* any -- of course the GM can mitigate them, but the question's seeking to understand them.

Comment: I'll also clarify that the possibility of annoying people isn't the operative issue here. This answer simply doesn't meet our quality requirements for objective expert answers.

Comment: While there is a valid point here, this answer could be greatly improved if it first addresses the actual question: _will any major plot points crumble if the DM includes a mundane forge in town?_ This would show that you are knowledgeable of the setting and the adventure which would also improve your frame challenge answer.